# How to check block is still running in background while uploading large audios on server from ios app

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, swift2, afnetworking

I'm using afnetworking multipart data to upload audio file to server. I have made one function for that and upload progress is in background so that user can use app while upload is running. The function code is :

```
class func postAudioURL(serverlink:String,methodname:String,param:NSDictionary,userName:String,password:String,filepath:String ,CompletionHandler:(success:Bool,response:NSDictionary) -> ())
    {
            print(serverlink + methodname + " and Param \(param)")

            let notallowchar : NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "01234").invertedSet
            let dateStr:String = "\(NSDate())"
            let resultStr:String = (dateStr.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(notallowchar) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("")
            let fileFormatedname = "RecordedAudio" + resultStr + ".wav"

            let audiodata : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filepath)!

            let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL: NSURL(string: serverlink))
            manager.requestSerializer.setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername(AUTH_USERNAME, password: AUTH_PWD)

            manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer(readingOptions: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)


            manager.POST(methodname, parameters: param, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formdata:AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
                    formdata.appendPartWithFileData(audiodata, name: "AudioFile", fileName: fileFormatedname, mimeType: "Audio/wav")
                }, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
                    responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
                    print("Response : " + responseObject.description)
                    CompletionHandler(success: true, response: responseObject as! NSDictionary)
                }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
                    error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription + "error code : \(error.code)")
                    var statuscode:String = ""
                    if(operation != nil) {
                        print("Response string error : \(operation.responseString) response code : \(operation.response.statusCode)")
                        statuscode = String("\(operation.response.statusCode)")

                    }
                    let errDict:NSDictionary = ["message":"\(error?.localizedDescription)","StatusCode":statuscode]
                    CompletionHandler(success: false,response: errDict)
            })
}
```

This code is working fine without any issue. I have write here to specify how I upload audio using completion block.

I have managed one local database to know that file is pending to upload, or sent or failed based on this upload function response. Most of the time I will get response either success or fail and I will update database accordingly.

The problem is that for some audio I can't get response either success or fail by any random issue or killing app. So that file stat becomes pending for all time. I need a solution for that like can I check there is some function or completion block is still running or not? By that I can update like if not running than I will update all pending state to fail and re-upload.

The problem is in rare case but still I need solution as it is considered as a bug in my app. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

=== EDIT

I have used background task expiration so that if app is going background than still audio upload can run, and ends that background task while success or fail.
My this function call is like

```
func uploadAudioServiceCall(metadata : String , myFileUrl : String) {

        self.bgTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({ () -> Void in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask)
        })
        let webParam : [String:String] = ["data" : metadata]

        WebService.postAudioURL(MAINLINK, methodname: UPLOAD_METHOD, param: webParam, userName: AUTH_USERNAME, password: AUTH_PWD, filepath: myFileUrl) { (success, response) -> () in
            if success == true {
                //"Response":"Success"
                // update state pending to sent
                  let allPending = //get pending count from database
                   if allPending.count == 0 {
                      UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask)
                   }
            } else {
                   // update state pending to fail
                  let allPending = //get pending count from database

                  if allPending.count == 0 {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask)
                  }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
     // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
```

almofire uploading will stop in this case, so there is no change to execute .success or .failure closures. you can set your 'pending' state as failed there.

Comment: I have used background to task to work in background. so does this affect this method?